# Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 70"

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to launch an iOS app with Appium on iPhone 5S real device. 
This is my set up

> Appium version : Version 1.10.0 (1.10.0.20181230.2)
>
> Xcode : Version10.1 beta 2
>
> Mac : 10.14.2
>
> iPhone : 5S
>
> iOS Version: 12.2

Desired Capabilities Used in Appium:

```
{
  "app": "/Users/shalika/Desktop/testapp.ipa",
  "deviceName": "YSS (12.1.3)",
  "udid": "2d5e0eb5faedbe17d590e2f72d3888b67a997e03",
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "platformName": "iOS"
}
```

When I start the appium session to run the app on my real device, appium log shows below error.

Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 70". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.

Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: ..how do you think we are able to reproduce your issue? Please edit question such someone can reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appium 1.10.0 did not include support for Xcode 10.2, which is required to build WebDriverAgent for iOS 12.2.

[Upgrade to the latest Appium version](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases) and your problem should go away.